# SPARQL Select Variable Prefix "?" and "$"

Tags: sparql

According to the specification, there is absolutely no difference between using the "?" and "$" variable prefix characters, even when mixing and matching. For example, this is totally legal:

```
SELECT  $title
WHERE   { <book1>  dc:title  ?title }
```

The [SPARQL docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/) even have this to add:

> A query variable is marked by the use of either "?" or "$"; the "?" or
>   "$" is not part of the variable name. In a query, $abc and ?abc
>   identify the same variable

Does anybody know why they created two redundant ways to prefix a variable? I didn't even know about the "$" until today while skimming the syntax's production rules. Using "?" is so common now, seems like "$" is just a lexical waste of a character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The original drafts of SPARQL started with just using '?' (which IIRC was taken from one of SPARQL's predecessor languages, RDQL). One reason the use of '$' was introduced was that at the time, the W3C SPARQL Working Group foresaw the use of existing ODBC/SQL tooling to handle SPARQL queries. Since '?' is a character with a distinct reserved meaning in SQL, it was felt an alternative or synonym should be allowed to better facilitate carrying SPARQL queries over ODBC connections. See [this mailing list discussion](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-rdf-dawg/2004OctDec/0160.html) for further details

As for why the Working Group standardised on allowing *both* (rather than just replacing the use of '?' outright): a vote was taken, several members objected to taking out the '?' completely (presumably because not everyone was convinced about the ODBC argument), so both were kept as a compromise.

Comment: I know that they're not specific programming questions,  per se,but I really like historical perspective answers, especially when primary sources are still available. It's nice to be reminded that most systems aren't designed from scratch or in a vacuum, but grow on existing technology.